# Проблема с Sort в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В yii2 advanced app использовал для сортировки постов на странице по дате yii\data\Sort. Установил, все работает, сортирует ASC DESC нормально. Но проблема вот в чем: мне надо, чтобы когда пользователь заходит на страницу, посты были уже по дефолту отсортированы в DESC. Таким образом я буду видеть новые посты. В yii\data\Sort есть свойство `'default' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],` то есть походу то что мне нужно. Но это условие не работает, не знаю, почему. В дебагер глядел. В базу только такой `SELECT * FROM post`. Без сортировки почему-то.

```
public function actionIndex(){

    $new_post = new Post();
    if ($new_post->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $new_post->user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $new_post->date = date('Y.m.d H:m:s');
        if($new_post->save()){
            $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->url);

        }
    }

    $sort = new Sort([
        'attributes' => [
            'date' => [
                'asc' => ['date' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],
                'label' => 'date',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    $query = Post::find()->orderBy($sort->orders);
    $like = Rating::find()->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->id,'rating'=>'like'])->indexBy('post_id')->all();
    $dislike = Rating::find()->where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->id,'rating'=>'dislike'])->indexBy('post_id')->all();
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(), 'pageSize'=>1]);
    $posts = $query->offset($pages->offset)
        ->limit($pages->limit)
        ->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'new_post' => $new_post,
        'pages'=>$pages,
        'posts'=>$posts,
        'sort' => $sort,
        'like'=>$like,
        'dislike'=>$dislike

    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как говорит [официальная документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html) - для default необходимо указывать просто `'default'=>SORT_DESC`. А в вашем случае лучше вообще ещё задавать `$defaultOrder`:

```
$sort = new Sort([
    'attributes' => [
        'date' => [
            'asc' => ['date' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['date' => SORT_DESC],
            'default' => SORT_DESC,
            'label' => 'date',
        ],
    ],
    'defaultOrder' => ['date'=>SORT_DESC],
]);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!